R optimx, recovering internally stored values after interruption
My optimization code runs for several days, and for external reasons, I have from time to time to interrupt/abort the code, by clicking on "stop" with R-studio.
Is there a possibility to see what is the content of the last optimization iteration, which has not been saved in an object (but must be in the computers' memory), or is this information definitively lost?
traceback() is not helpful.
I use the optimx package.
The following simple code can be run (and has to be interrupted by hand) to illustrate my question.
require(optimx) 
# genrose function code
genrose.f<- function(x, gs=NULL){ # objective function
  ## One generalization of the Rosenbrock banana valley function (n parameters)
  n <- length(x)
  if(is.null(gs)) { gs=100.0 }
  fval<-1.0 + sum (gs*(x[1:(n-1)]^2 - x[2:n])^2 + (x[2:n] - 1)^2)
  return(fval)
}

startx <- seq(1:100) / 5
n <- length( startx )

# Here is the command which has to be stopped by hand after few seconds
ans = optimx( startx, fn=genrose.f, gr=NULL, hess=NULL, 
              method=c("Nelder-Mead"),
              control=list( maxit=5000000, save.failures=TRUE, trace=3), gs=10)


I would try to solve things faster. (1) Use a better-suited solver. For large problems, use a large-scale sparse solver. (2) Provide a better starting point. (3) Provide gradients. (4) Don't use Nelder-Mead (a derivative-free method) if not absolutely necessary (5) if you want to use a derivative-free method anyway, don't solve large models.

Note that require should only be used as the condition in an if (...).  If optimx is not installed you want it to fail at that point so  use library instead of require.

@Erwin Kalvelagen: thank you for your recommandations. My code is actually more elaborated than the one posted here, and also iterates using gradient based numerical methods like BFGS and nlminb.

All the methods you mention are for small, dense problems. Large, sparse problems are better solved with large-scale, sparse solvers. I don't know what "also iterates using gradient based numerical methods" means. All methods iterate even on easy problems.

@ErwinKalvelagen, I don't think we know enough about the OP's problem to give useful advice about how to speed it up. Your advice (2) and (3) is generally useful, although not easy to implement (some problems are too complicated to derive gradients analytically, and automatic differentiation is not easily available in R ...)

@ErwinKalvelagen, if possible, could you provide an R function/package allowing to solve/optimize large-scale sparse propblems? Would be helpfull to understand the difference with other "usual" solvers/optimizers. Thanks a lot !!

@Enrico: maybe you can experiment with the BB package described by Varadhan, R., & Gilbert, P. (2009). BB: An R Package for Solving a Large System of Nonlinear Equations and for Optimizing a High-Dimensional Nonlinear Objective Function. Journal of Statistical Software, 32(4), 1–26. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v032.i04

You can modify your objective function to store the information about the last call (not exactly the same as the last iteration of the optimization algorithm, as an iteration usually involves several calls to the objective function) in the function's environment, e.g.
library(optimx) 
last_it <- 0
last_pars <- NA_real_
last_val <- NA_real_
genrose.f <- function(x, gs=100) {
  last_pars <<- x
  last_it <<- last_it + 1
  n <- length(x)
  fval <- 1.0 + sum (gs*(x[1:(n-1)]^2 - x[2:n])^2 + (x[2:n] - 1)^2)
  last_val <<- fval
  return(fval)
}

startx <- seq(1:100) / 5
n <- length( startx )

ans = optimx( startx, fn=genrose.f, gr=NULL, hess=NULL, 
              method=c("Nelder-Mead"),
              control=list( maxit=5000000, save.failures=TRUE,
              trace=3), gs=10)

After stopping:
> last_val
[1] 9954591
> last_it
[1] 88872
> head(last_pars)
[1]  8.071216  6.878062 -4.777840  6.682326  7.567179  7.840888

In this case the environment of the function is the global workspace. If you're going to use <<- you need to make sure that the last_* variables are defined externally before you run the function. If you want to be slightly more careful, or if you were going to include this code in a package being submitted to CRAN (who disapprove of <<- in package code), you would use assign("last_pars", x, parent.frame()) instead.

thank you! It works very well and increases system time by less than 1%.
